# How I can dynamically change a WPF control into another?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to do a component where checkboxes change into radiobuttons when certain property changes. I have no idea how to do that kind of change in xaml. The checkbox is in a datatemplate as shown below. Now I just need some kind of logic to change it into a radiobutton.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Add another `RadioButton`, change the `Visibility` of the two controls according to your logic.

Comment: The problem seems to be that there can only be one control in the DataTemplate.

Comment: Enclose them with a `Grid` or `StackPanel`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Especially when there are a lot of instances, the solution of having **both** controls within the `DataTemplate` and changing visibility might not be ideal considering performance and memory usage. In this case, a DataTemplateSelector might do the trick - see [this tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Comment: Collapsing isn't terrible and lets you animate a transition. The element is removed from the measure and layout process and WPF's dependency property structure is designed too minimize memory usage in large scene graphs.

Comment: You're right, it definitely isn't, and I'm using the collapsing approach in several of my applications (with a low number of items). I just wanted to show that there is an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

you can put both `CheckBox` and `RadioButton` in one container (`StackPanel` for example) in `DataTemplate` and just collapse one of them according to your condition using `DataTrigger`.

i hope it'll help you. sorry for my pure english.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBoxHeader">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButtonHeader">
            <RadioButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RadioButton.Style>
        </RadioButton>                        
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, do not place just some code.